# Do we need to shutdown DB/Stop DB service before Windows server patching

Tags: mongodb, windows, patching

Before patching Windows server, do we need to shut down any DB or stop DB service.

If we need to shutdown a MongoDB on a node(Windows server) which is part of a replica set, what we need to before patching windows server..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade a replicaset, please follow [MongoDB upgrade process](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-replica-set/#upgrade-process).
Here's a quick summary:

- upgrade all secondary nodes - if necessary check if everything's working properly
- stepDown and upgrade the primary node
- set the `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` to the version matching your upgrade